# Error 405 when trying to control Sonos through PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, upnp, sonos

This is my error:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'Error sending command: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Allow: GET, HEAD Content-type: text/html Server: Linux UPnP/1.0 Sonos/24.0-69180 (BR100) Connection: close
Error 405

Method Not Allowed
' in C:\wamp\www\PHPSonos.inc.php:240 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\PHPSonos.inc.php(148): PHPSonos->sendPacket('POST /MediaRend...') #1 C:\wamp\www\demo.php(9): PHPSonos->SetRadio('x-rincon-mp3rad...') #2 {main} nope.
```

I'm hosting this server through the latest version of WAMP on port 8080.  Whenever I try to visit my main page, demo.php, it's supposed to send a SOAP/UPNP request to the sonos player.  Unfortunately, it always comes up with error 405.  I need help fixing this ASAP.

This is my code:
Main page:

```
<?php
include("PHPSonos.inc.php");

$sonos = new PHPSonos("192.168.1.5"); //Sonos ZP IPAdresse

//Grundfunktionen
try {
//$sonos->Pause();
$sonos->SetRadio("x-rincon-mp3radio://players.creacast.com/creacast/klassik/playlist.pls");
$sonos->Play();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e;
}
//$sonos->Play();
//$sonos->Next();
//$sonos->Previous();
//$sonos->Rewind();
//$sonos->SetVolume(1); //0-100 in %
//$sonos->SetPlayMode("NORMAL"); //REPEAT_ALL, SHUFFLE, NORMAL
//$sonos->SetMute(false); //True = MUTE, False = KEIN MUTE

//Klassik Radio abspielen
//$sonos->SetRadio("x-rincon-mp3radio://players.creacast.com/creacast/klassik/playlist.pls");
//$sonos->Play();

//Neue MP3 abspielen
//$sonos->ClearQueue(); //Playlist löschen
//$sonos->AddToQueue("x-file-cifs://ipsserver/Public/test.mp3"); //Datei hinzufügen
//$sonos->SetQueue("x-rincon-queue:RINCON_"."HIER DIE MAC DES PLAYERS ZB: FFEEDDCCBBAA"."01400#0"); //Playlist auswählen (Nötig, wenn Radio vorher ausgewählt war)
//$sonos->Play();
?>
<html>
<body>
nope.
</body>
</html>
```

The script it's importing:

```
<?php

//Sonos PHP Script
//Copyright: Michael Maroszek
//Version: 1.0, 09.07.2009

class PHPSonos {
    private $address = "";

    public function __construct( $address ) {
       $this->address = $address;
    }

    public function Pause()
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 252
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Pause"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:Pause xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID></u:Pause></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function Play()
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 266
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Play"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:Play xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Speed>1</Speed></u:Play></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function Next()
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 250
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Next"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:Next xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID></u:Next></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function Previous()
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 258
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Previous"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:Previous xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID></u:Previous></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function Rewind()
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 296
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Seek"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:Seek xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Unit>REL_TIME</Unit><Target>00:00:00</Target></u:Seek></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function SetVolume($volume)
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/RenderingControl/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 32'.strlen($volume).'
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#SetVolume"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:SetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Channel>Master</Channel><DesiredVolume>'.$volume.'</DesiredVolume></u:SetVolume></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function SetMute($mute)
    {

        if($mute) { $mute = "1"; } else { $mute = "0"; }

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/RenderingControl/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 314
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#SetMute"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:SetMute xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Channel>Master</Channel><DesiredMute>'.$mute.'</DesiredMute></u:SetMute></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function SetPlayMode($mode)
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: '.(291+strlen($mode)).'
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#SetPlayMode"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:SetPlayMode xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><NewPlayMode>'.$mode.'</NewPlayMode></u:SetPlayMode></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function SetRadio($radio)
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: '.(974+strlen(htmlspecialchars($radio))).'
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#SetAVTransportURI"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><CurrentURI>'.htmlspecialchars($radio).'</CurrentURI><CurrentURIMetaData>&lt;DIDL-Lite xmlns:dc=&quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&quot; xmlns:upnp=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/&quot; xmlns:r=&quot;urn:schemas-rinconnetworks-com:metadata-1-0/&quot; xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/&quot;&gt;&lt;item id=&quot;R:0/0/0&quot; parentID=&quot;R:0/0&quot; restricted=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;IP-Symcon Radio&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.item.audioItem.audioBroadcast&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;desc id=&quot;cdudn&quot; nameSpace=&quot;urn:schemas-rinconnetworks-com:metadata-1-0/&quot;&gt;SA_RINCON65031_&lt;/desc&gt;&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/DIDL-Lite&gt;</CurrentURIMetaData></u:SetAVTransportURI></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function SetQueue($queue)
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: '.(342+strlen(htmlspecialchars($queue))).'
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#SetAVTransportURI"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><CurrentURI>'.htmlspecialchars($queue).'</CurrentURI><CurrentURIMetaData></CurrentURIMetaData></u:SetAVTransportURI></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function ClearQueue()
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: 290
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#RemoveAllTracksFromQueue"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:RemoveAllTracksFromQueue xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID></u:RemoveAllTracksFromQueue></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function AddToQueue($file)
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: '.(438+strlen(htmlspecialchars($file))).'
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#AddURIToQueue"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:AddURIToQueue xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><EnqueuedURI>'.htmlspecialchars($file).'</EnqueuedURI><EnqueuedURIMetaData></EnqueuedURIMetaData><DesiredFirstTrackNumberEnqueued>0</DesiredFirstTrackNumberEnqueued><EnqueueAsNext>1</EnqueueAsNext></u:AddURIToQueue></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function RemoveFromQueue($track)
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: '.(307+strlen($track)).'
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#RemoveTrackFromQueue"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:RemoveTrackFromQueue xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><ObjectID>Q:0/'.$track.'</ObjectID></u:RemoveTrackFromQueue></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    public function SetTrack($track)
    {

$content='POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1
CONNECTION: close
HOST: '.$this->address.':1400
CONTENT-LENGTH: '.(288+strlen($track)).'
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Seek"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:Seek xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Unit>TRACK_NR</Unit><Target>'.$track.'</Target></u:Seek></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

        $this->sendPacket($content);
    }

    private function sendPacket( $content )
    {
        $fp = fsockopen($this->address, 1400 /* Port */, $errno, $errstr, 10);
        if (!$fp)
            throw new Exception("Error opening socket: ".$errstr." (".$errno.")");

        fputs ($fp, $content);
        $ret = "";
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $ret.= fgets($fp,128);
        }
        fclose($fp);

        if(strpos($ret, "200 OK") === false)
            throw new Exception("Error sending command: ".$ret);
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the renderer works according to UPnP spec (I say that explicitly because it's a fairly big assumption).

According to spec control messages should be sent like this:

1. Send the control message with regular `POST`, do not use the soap `MAN` header
2. If the answer is 405, send again using `M-POST` and include the `MAN` header with value "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

The PHP script you're including does not implement the second part. See [UPnP Device Architecture pdf](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf), section 3.2.1.